# How to save a Hugo site as HTML files?

Tags: html, markdown

I have a site in Hugo markdown. It is mainly composed of markdown (.md) files.

I have the full Hugo site, with `public/`, `layout/`, `layout/shortcodes/` folders, etc. I am using a docsy theme, on Windows. I launch the site with the command `hugo server -D`, and I can see the site in my browser at `localhost:1313/docs`.

When the Hugo site is running, those `.md` files are automatically published on the localhost site; so I imagine that [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/) must convert those files to HTML internally.

I would like to find a way of automatically converting the .md [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/) site files from markdown to .HTML files **on the disk**. In other words, I want a *mirror* of the .md file structure, but in HTML, in the form of files, on the disk. I imagine that is what the Hugo site does anyway, so that the browser can show the site. But it does that on the fly, and I can't find a way of saving the files on the disk.

Comment: It may be worth further expanding on the exact steps you're taking when using Hugo. For instance, if you haven't added a theme or run e.g. `hugo -D`, there won't be any HTML files in the `public` directory of the website folder.

Comment: @Anaksunaman : I have run the hugo server -D, I can see the site in my browser at localhost://1313/docs. What I am trying to get are .HTML files on the disk, corresponding to the hugo site

Comment: @Anaksunaman I launched just `hugo` and now I see the .HTML files. That is the answer I was looking for. I would mark it as the answer to the question, but I don't see any command to that effect.

Comment: Comments can't be marked as answers, but that's fine. I have converted my comment to an answer. However, you can mark your own answer if you wish. In any case, I am glad to hear things have been resolved. =)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I have run `hugo server -D`.

For clarity, `hugo server -D` will not create `.html` files. It only serves files on the fly (as you suggest in your original question).

To generate `.html` files in the `public` folder of the website, you must either run just `hugo` or e.g. `hugo -D` at the command line, generally in the same directory as `config.toml` (i.e. you shouldn't include `server` in the command).